# Mysql order_id error

Tags: mysql

I'm making a database for our project at the university. I get the error:

```
CREATE DATABASE P4_Projekt
USE P4_Projekt
CREATE TABLE shop_table
(
Shop_ID INT (12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Shop_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
City VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
Address VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
Zip_code INT (4) NOT NULL,
Phone_number CHAR (8) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Shop_id)
)

CREATE TABLE Orders
(
Order_id INT (12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Customer_id INT (12) NOT NULL,
Pickup_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
Products_id INT (12) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT Orders_Product_id_fk
FOREIGN KEY (Product_id)
REFERENCES Products (Product_id),
Notes VARCHAR (250),
Price FLOAT (8) NOT NULL,
Pre_paid BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
Status_ TINYINT (2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Order_id)
)

CREATE TABLE User
(
User_id INT (12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
First_name VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
Last_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
Address VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
ZIP_code INT (4) NOT NULL,
Phone_number CHAR (8) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR (50),
PRIMARY KEY (User_id)
)

CREATE TABLE Products
(
Product_id INT (12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name_ VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
Price FLOAT (8) NOT NULL,
Description VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
Production_time TIME (6) NOT NULL,
IMG BLOB,
PRIMARY KEY (Product_id)
)
```

I get the error "Key column 'product_id' doesn't exist in table, when I try to create the order table. Is it about the foreign key?

Answer (score 1):

you miss one comma before the primary key line, change like this can work well

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
Order_id INT (12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Customer_id INT (12) NOT NULL,
Pickup_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
Products_id INT (12) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT Orders_Product_id_fk
FOREIGN KEY (Product_id)
REFERENCES Products (Product_id),
Notes VARCHAR (250),
Price FLOAT (8) NOT NULL,
Pre_paid BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
Status_ TINYINT (2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Order_id)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

comma mistake , use this

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
 (
  Order_id INT (12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Customer_id INT (12) NOT NULL,
 Pickup_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
 Products_id INT (12) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT Orders_Product_id_fk
 FOREIGN KEY (Product_id)
 REFERENCES Products (Product_id),
  Notes VARCHAR (250),
 Price FLOAT (8) NOT NULL,
Pre_paid BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
Status_ TINYINT (2) NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (Order_id)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use semicolon after every closing table.

Like

```
CREATE TABLE User(
User_id INT (12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
First_name VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
Last_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
Address VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
ZIP_code INT (4) NOT NULL,
Phone_number CHAR (8) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR (50),
PRIMARY KEY (User_id)
);
```

Comment: MySQL don't care about that

Comment: If you use semicolon after every table like on his example, you easly find the problem.

Comment: ups, I meant that MySQL Workbench didn't care about semicolons. And I still get the same error